# SVN update not working

Tags: eclipse, svn

From what i know - 
SVN Team > Update (^ALT U) updates the local version of the code with the changes in the repository - so that 
the non-conflicting changes in the repository are merged into my local code here 
and the conflicting ones are merged-still-and-marked to show the conflicts between my code and the one in the code base. 
however, i'm not getting my local code updated when i do the update.

I also tried Team > Update to Revision (^ALT D) with the "right kind of options".

How can i work this?

Is this an issue with SVN settings/preferences?

I'm running it on Eclipse/Luna. New project/installations, straightforward installation and default SVN settings on Eclipse.

TIA.

Note: I've seen [svn update not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269745/svn-update-not-updating) and [svn update is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15244892/svn-update-is-not-working) among some other discussions.

//=========================================

**EDIT:**

Running

```
Team->Show History
```

in Java view shows the revisions list. I see the same list when i do `Show History` in `SVN Repository Exploring` view. 
This list seems all OK-- the kind i've seen on my other uses of SVN.

Running

```
svn info
```

in command prompt gave:

```
svn info
'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I ran this command on a local shell in `Remote Systems` view as described in the accepted answer of [Is there an Eclipse plugin to run system shell in the Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562600/is-there-an-eclipse-plugin-to-run-system-shell-in-the-console).

Comment: A few questions that might be helpful: What do you see when you right click on the folder you are trying to update and select Team->Show History? Have you tried doing the update from the cmd line (svn up), what do you see when you try that? What do you see if you execute "svn info" from the cmd line? What is not being updated (is there a specific change you are expecting that you are not seeing)? What do you see if you switch to the "SVN Repository Exploring" view and right click on the folder in the repository and select "Show History"?

Comment: @John - pls see edit. what i expect to and do not see is pretty much in the Q actually. update isn't updating my local code with the revisions in the code base. thx.

Comment: Also, I assumed you are using the subclipse plug in. This is the version that I'm using: http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, some other suggetsions (if you haven't tried yet): right click on the top level folder of the project and try Team->Refresh/Clean Up and then try right-click->Refresh on the same.  Right click on the top level folder and see what you get for Compare With->Latest From Repository. Select a specific file you think is not up to date with the latest from repository, right click and select Compare With->Latest From Repository.  As a last resort you can copy the project to a backup location and do a fresh check out from head.

You can get a svn client from here (I use the one available from collabnet, you will need the version that matches the version the server is running):

http://www.subversiondownload.com

If you don't have this resource already, its a good one to have if you have more svn in your future:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/